# Regression on constant

Tags: r

I need to run a regression on a constant. In Eviews, I don't need to put any thing as a predictor when I run a regression on constant.I don't know how to do that in R. Does any one knows what should I write in this commnd?

fit= lm(r~?)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a constant as `1` in a formula:

```
r <- 1:5
fit <- lm(r ~ 1)
summary(fit)
# Call:
#   lm(formula = r ~ 1)
# 
# Residuals:
#   1         2         3         4         5 
# -2.00e+00 -1.00e+00  2.22e-16  1.00e+00  2.00e+00 
# 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
# (Intercept)   3.0000     0.7071   4.243   0.0132 *
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 1.581 on 4 degrees of freedom
```

Note that you don't need `lm` to get this result:

```
mean(r)
#[1] 3
sd(r)/sqrt(length(r))
#[1] 0.7071068
```

However, you might want to use `lm` in order to have a Null model against which you can compare other models ...

**Edit:**

Since you comment that you need "the p-value", I suggest to use a t-test instead.

```
t.test(r)
#   One Sample t-test
#
#data:  r
#t = 4.2426, df = 4, p-value = 0.01324
#alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
#95 percent confidence interval:
# 1.036757 4.963243
#sample estimates:
#mean of x 
#        3
```

This is equivalent, but more efficient computationally.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes, I need to look at the P-value of this regression that's why I want to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to the t-test. The results are roughly the same.

Comment: @Rfinance No, they must be exactly the same. Otherwise you do something wrong.